sub_filter not replacing the strings in iframes
I'm using Nginx as revproxy for one of the application. One of the requirement is to replace the domain string in html pages. I was able to achieve this using sub_filter_types but the iframes from the page still contains actual domain where our application is running.
Example:
Users are exposed to abc.com(where nginx is running) and actual application is running on example.com. When users hit abc.com the login and rest of the application works as expected but iframes src is still showing example.com.
Nginx Config:
      server {
        listen       [::]:10000  ssl;
        server_name  abc.com;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        proxy_redirect https://example.com/ $scheme://abc.com/;
        
        sub_filter_types *;
        sub_filter example.com abc.com;
        sub_filter_once off;

        location / {
          proxy_pass https://example.com;
          proxy_set_header Host example.com;
        }
      }

Please let me know how to address this issue. Thanks
I was playing around with below configuration without sub_filter_types but issue still exists.
sub_filter xyz.com abc.com;
sub_filter_once off;

Does the iframe specify abc.com as the source domain? Or does it fetch the content from elsewhere?

The iframe src is showing as example.com instead of abc.com. The content is fetched from example.com where actual application is running.
